# scrollview scroll delegation

Tags: iphone

Is there any delegate or some notification which tells that scroll view has been scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the end of a scroll with the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate.

Comment: Alright. I am testing a application and something strange is happening. In my UI when I click on a textfield, it comes up as keyboard has to come below it. Now if I click on my done button I get the desired result with all my UI components placed correctly. But when I again click on that textfield and scroll the view down and then press done, my whole view goes up by amount of scroll I did in downward direction and then I cannot scroll to see my UI components went up. I am wondering why and how this is happening . I have checked with debugging mode and nothing wierd I noticed. Any clue sir?

Answer (score 2):

[UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)